# How to create a composite uniqueKey in schema.xml?

Tags: solr

Is it possible to create a composite uniqueKey in schema.xml? Or is it better to concatenate the unique fields into one unique string id field in the source data?

If it's possible, and if it's not that big of a difference, I would prefer to do the former because it would save me a bit of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed here [How to set multiple fields as uniqueKey in solr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24454755/how-to-set-multiple-fields-as-uniquekey-in-solr) or there http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Multiple-uniqueKey-fields-td472939.html u cannot simply add multiple fields. Ud need to combine them into one field, but this can not be a multivalued field.